# Django: render a txt file with linebreaks

Tags: python, django

I need to return a txt file as HTTPResponse in Django. The file needs to contain multiple lines generated from a list (ex. ['line one', 'line two']).
If I use DTL and a template, I cannot insert any line breaks except for html-specific ones. So, my current solution is to write lines to response with csv.writer. It works, but isn't there a more elegant way to get a txt file that looks like this?

```
line one
line two
```

Update: I guess, my problem is that I need CR,LF linebreaks.

Comment: Why would the csv writer be less elegant than using an extra template that contains nothing more than a for loop? It certainly depends on how you expect that part of the code to evolve. If it's ok for the near future then just use the csv writer or simply join a list of strings with the line breaks you want and return that. Make sure to set the correct content type.

Comment: I didn't mean using an extra template. I meant more concise than importing csv. Just a way to hardcode a linebreak into httpresponse.

Comment: In that case you should add your current code to your answer (edit the answer, don't do that in a comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a list of strings and want to output it in a response as one string only, the easiest is to use `join`:

```
lines = ['line one', 'line two']
response_content = '\n'.join(lines)
return HttpResponse(response_content, content_type="text/plain")
```

Inside a template that would be:

```
 {% for line in mylines %}
     {{ line }}
 {% endfor %}
```

This should put each line on its own line in the output.

Comment: This is what I did before resorting to csv. But this gave me line breaks that notepad doesn't recognize.

Comment: Notepad might not use the regular `\n` linebreaks. In that case you might have to change the join separator to `\r\n` or something like this. See also http://superuser.com/a/362092 and search for "notepad linebreaks" (or more general ms windows). You might want to consider changing the encoding of your output to windows latin1 encoding if this will be a file specifically for that OS.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Changing the separator to \r\n is the concise solution, I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion is simply false. Django template language is in no way limited to HTML; it works just as well for any format and you can quite happily use it to generate a text file.

Comment: Well, how do I add the line breaks then? I've tried it, see. Assuming, that my lines are in a list called 'mylines':

    {% for line in mylines %}
    {{ line|linebreak }}
    {{% endfor %}}

or something like that would either give me <p> or <br> tags, but not real line breaks.

Comment: You can just enter a newline in your template. Or use `\n`.

Comment: This was the very first thing that I tried, man. Turns out, that the line breaks were there, just not the ones, that I need. I need windows-style ones, CR,LF.